# How to find the XPATH of these dropdown menus on youtube for use in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to schedule youtube uploads using a bot with python / Selenium. I am able to open the website, upload the video, and continue through the upload options but when I try to schedule a time and date it does not work as I am not selecting the right element.

[image: Youtube Studio dropdown box]

I want to be able to change the date and time values.

For the date element, I have tried

```
schedule_button_d = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "datepicker-trigger"] / ytcp -     dropdown - trigger / div / div[2] / span')
schedule_button_d.click()
schedule_button_d.clear()
schedule_button_d.send_keys("13 Jul 2023")
schedule_button_d.submit()
```

and

```
schedule_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "datepicker-trigger"]')
```

with the same code after, and similar for the time element with different XPATH id.

Each time the program closes with an error unable to locate an element or no such element.

I have also tried locating the element with text contains but it does not work.

Is there another way to find these elements?
I am using Selenium 4.10.0, python 3.11.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CSS selectors below:

Radio: `#schedule-radio-button #radioContainer`

Time input: `.scheduled-info-container.ytcp-datetime-picker input`

Open dropdown:  `.scheduled-info-container .ytcp-dropdown-trigger svg`